# Sqlite : Locking the database file for write operation

Tags: sqlite

I have the following question for SQLite.

1. When I am doing write operation does sqlite locks the entire database file or only the particular table ?
2. Suppose I have some DB and I start a `begin` and then I perform millions of write operations. So, I know a `-journal` file is created for those million operations`. The question is : Will the database (non-journal) file be locked before I commit or those transactions continue in parallel in journal file which locks the table for sometime ONLY when I commit?

**EDIT**

If I start `begin` and `commit` comes 50 seconds later. Then will the file be locked at beginning or after those 50 s when DB starts commiting?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite always locks the entire database.

The file is locked only when SQLite actually needs to write to it, but this is certain happen if you do millions of operations, because the changes will not fit into the cache.
(The DB file is locked at the first write, and unlocked when the transaction ends.)

Comment: Suppose I did some 1000 transactions that can fit into cache. What happens then? Will it lock file only while commiting?

Comment: Every commit will write.

Comment: Does that mean that it won't lock for individual write operations inside `begin-commit` but instead for the commit only?

Comment: Sorry If I am not able to express my doubt. I want to know, if I start `begin` and `commit` comes 50 seconds  later. Then will the file be locked at beginning or after those 50 s when DB starts commiting?

Comment: That depends on what [kind of BEGIN](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) you use.